# Java Regex with one matching and two negations in any position

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, case-insensitive

I have to match a keyword provided it is not in a sentence compounding an URL nor certain words. For instance, with the keyword **.NET**, the string must not have **http://**, and the characters after **.NET** must not be **work** or **flix**, but can be **framework** or any other word, or even nothing. The regex must be case insensitive.

I have these examples to match:

- The framework **.NET**
- That is **.NET**Framework
- Microsoft**.NET**
- **.NET**Framework (update)
- **.net**framework (update)
- **.net** (update)

And these examples to NOT match:

- This is a URL http://www.my**.net**/ to not match
- The Network isn't matching because the missing point
- The **.NET**work is up
- Microsoft**.Net**workAndSharingCenter
- 4df9e0f8**.net**flix_mcm4njqhnhss8
- **.net**work (update)
- **.Net**work (update)

I have written this pattern:

```
(?i)(.*)(?!.*http\:\/\/.*)(\.net)(?!.*work)(?!.*flix)(.*)
```

I have coded these test cases bellow, but `testMatch_02()` and `testNotMatch_01()` both fail, and I'm not being able to figure it out why.

**UPDATE 1**

I have added three more test cases: `testNotMatch_03()`, `testNotMatch_04()` and `testNotMatch_05()`. They are running OK against the given regex. But `testMatch_02()` and `testNotMatch_01()` are still failing as said before. I have decided to add these new test cases to clarify that not always there will be a space before **.NET**.

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed a few the pattern from `(?i)(.*)(?!.*http\:\/\/.*)(\.net)(?!.*work)(?!.*flix)(.*)` to `(?i)(.*)(?!http\\:\\/\\/)(.*)(\\.net)(?!work|flix)(.*)`. Thus all test cases run OK except `testNotMatch_01()`. I have updated the tests' code, in case anyone wants run it with this new pattern.

**UPDATE 3**

Please, I'll be very thankful whether someone run the test case before and make assumptions based in it. We can avoid turning this question in a chat conversation.

**UPDATE 4**

It is important to say that not only the listed examples must pass, but rather regex must validate according to what is described in the original wording of the question. After talking with @Thomas, I have included three new matching and two new not-matching examples as so the test cases to each one in the code bellow, along with the regex provided by @Thomas. Also, I have changed the code to be like the code provided by @Thomas, which is simpler and shorter, as his regex.

```
package com.regex;

public class TestRegex
{
    //private static final String regex = "(?i)(.*)(?!.*http\\:\\/\\/.*)(\\.net)(?!.*work)(?!.*flix)(.*)";
    //private static final String regex = "(?i)(.*)(?!http\\:\\/\\/)(.*)(\\.net)(?!work|flix)(.*)";
    private static final String regex = "(?i).*( |microsoft).net($|Framework)"; //@Thomas

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "The framework .NET";
        System.out.println("testMatch_01() must match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "That is .NETFramework";
        System.out.println("testMatch_02() must match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "Microsoft.NET";
        System.out.println("testMatch_03() must match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "That is .netframework";
        System.out.println("testMatch_04() must match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = ".netframework";
        System.out.println("testMatch_05() must match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = ".NETFramework";
        System.out.println("testMatch_06() must match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "This is a URL http://www.my.net";
        System.out.println("testNotMatch_01() must not match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "The Network isn't matching because the missing point";
        System.out.println("testNotMatch_02() must not match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "The .NETwork is up";
        System.out.println("testNotMatch_03() must not match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter";
        System.out.println("testNotMatch_04() must not match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));

        str = "4df9e0f8.netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8";
        System.out.println("testNotMatch_05() must not match: [" + str + "] =>  " + str.matches(regex));
    }

}
```

**The output for the above code is:**

with regex `(?i)(.*)(?!http\\:\\/\\/)(.*)(\\.net)(?!work|flix)(.*)`
`testNotMatch_01()` fail

```
testMatch_01() must match: [The framework .NET] =>  true
testMatch_02() must match: [That is .NETFramework] =>  true
testMatch_03() must match: [Microsoft.NET] =>  true
testMatch_04() must match: [That is .netframework] =>  true
testMatch_05() must match: [.netframework] =>  true
testMatch_06() must match: [.NETFramework] =>  true
testNotMatch_01() must not match: [This is a URL http://www.my.net] =>  true
testNotMatch_02() must not match: [The Network isn't matching because the missing point] =>  false
testNotMatch_03() must not match: [The .NETwork is up] =>  false
testNotMatch_04() must not match: [Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter] =>  false
testNotMatch_05() must not match: [4df9e0f8.netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8] =>  false
```

with regex `(?i).*( |microsoft).net($|Framework)`
`testMatch_05()` and `testMatch_06()` fail

```
testMatch_01() must match: [The framework .NET] =>  true
testMatch_02() must match: [That is .NETFramework] =>  true
testMatch_03() must match: [Microsoft.NET] =>  true
testMatch_04() must match: [That is .netframework] =>  true
testMatch_05() must match: [.netframework] =>  false
testMatch_06() must match: [.NETFramework] =>  false
testNotMatch_01() must not match: [This is a URL http://www.my.net] =>  false
testNotMatch_02() must not match: [The Network isn't matching because the missing point] =>  false
testNotMatch_03() must not match: [The .NETwork is up] =>  false
testNotMatch_04() must not match: [Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter] =>  false
testNotMatch_05() must not match: [4df9e0f8.netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8] =>  false
```

Comment: What about `(?i)\s\.net(?!work)`? -> https://regex101.com/r/kI9rA9/1

Comment: @JoshCroizer with this pattern, all "not-match" test cases are OK, but `testMatch_01()` and `testMatch_02()` have been failed. I have edited the question just now for clarity.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I see that you have used a PHP flavor of regex. In Java it seems to be a little bit different because those mentioned test cases fail.

Comment: What about `(?|(?|.*|Microsoft)\.net(?|Framework|$))`

Comment: @Thomas this results in an exception: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 2
(?|(?|.*|Microsoft)\.net(?|Framework|$))`

Comment: This `.*.net($|Framework)` should pass your tests

Comment: @Thomas not really. This pattern have increased the number of test cases that fail. With it, besides `testMatch_02()` and `testNotMatch_01()`, now `testMatch_01()` and `testMatch_03()` fail too.

Comment: add `(?i)` in front of the regex

Comment: @Thomas Unfortunately, it also does not solve the issue. But thanks to you and to everyone who made suggestions so far.

Comment: Well that's strange, because it [works](https://ideone.com/jlfkvO)...

Comment: @Thomas I try your code, and it works, except for one point: the missing case `testNotMatch_01()` with string `"This is a URL http://www.my.net"`. So I add this case in the end of your code, and it [fails](https://ideone.com/Ox72sf). `str = "This is a URL http://www.my.net"; System.out.println(str + " => " + str.matches(regex));`

Comment: @Thomas I see why it works for you. I guess you do the case I said but the service ideone.com changed the original URL to `"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...y.net/"` and this matches, but not the original URL `"http://www.my.net"`. I have forked your code and added the case, and after some tries, it changes the URL to me too and the case works as for you. http://imgur.com/a/s9dd8 - so I have ran your code in a real IDE desktop just in case, and it fails every time in the last case `"This is a URL http://www.my.net"`.

Comment: @Thomas Here is the output from IDE desktop http://imgur.com/UBECzut

Comment: TestNotMatch_01 string is `This is a URL http://www.my.net/ to not match`. Anyway, try with `(?i).*( |microsoft).net($|Framework)`

Comment: @Thomas Yes :) this works. But... as mentioned before, I need this to be case insensitive, so I have tested against `"That is .netframework"` and it fails. It seems like `(?i)` is not being respected by Java Regex. 
Although all other specified test cases have passed. In any case, this already helps me because I can turn all string to lower case before doing the match. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas After the initial excitement of seeing that all test cases passed, I decided to look in with more detail and according to the first statement of this question. After running the code again: the string "That is .NETFramework" works, no matter the case; what does not work is the string ".NETFramework" alone, or even ".NET". These two strings are not in the sample list, but serves as proof of the solution because they are in accordance with the wording of the question. So I updated the question, in case anyone else wants to help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex works for all of your examples:

```
^(?i)(?!.*http:\/\/).*?\.net(?!work|flix).*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/cgHD15E93E).

Note that your negative example "The Network isn't matching because the missing point" is misleading, because it also shouldn't match because ".net" is followed by "work".

Comment: Yes! You're right. I see what I'm doing wrong, I was missing `?` after `.*` in the middle of the regex. It works even without `^` in the beginning. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Expert-SaidNoOneEver it works with or without the "?" - I added that for performance reasons (in case the input is long it saves a lot of back tracking). The "^" is necessary - test it yourself on the link in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the demo. I just ran the very code for test cases provided in this same question against your regex and it worked. I see now the live demo you provided is for Ruby Regex. I am using Java, which has a regex flavor a little bit different from Ruby regex, it is more like Perl regex. As I could verify, in Java, even without `^` in your regex, all the test cases work. I know that `^` makes matches from the beginning of a string. Any way, I was just trying to figure out what really makes the difference, so I cut some chars here and there like those and test it again.

Comment: Testing and experimenting, I see that what really makes the difference and solves the question was to put `.*` (which was just after `(?i)`) into the group ahead, as you did. In the beginning, I had two of `.*`, one outside and one inside the negation group, as can be seen in the first commented regex declaration in the code, but unfortunatelly I have cut the wrong one, I cut that inside the group and kept the one outside. So, I had "(?i)(.*)(?!http..." and now I have "(?i)(?!.*http...". Thanx!

Comment: I tested the performance with and without "?" in the middle of the regex, as you said, but at least in Java and to my specific case, it doesn't make any difference. But good to know. I'm just started to learn regex. Thanx again.